# In Bevy ECS, what is a good way to have entities reference each other?

Tags: entity-component-system, rust, bevy

I am wondering if there is a better way than storing the entity ID. For the sake of example, let's assume I have a world with many entities who implement the component Name. Every x amount of time I want these entities to print "Hello, I am *greeterName*, have a nice day *greetedName*".

My current way to go would be to create a component `BestFriend`, and to store in it the entity ID of the best friend entity. Then I would make a system `GreetBestFriend` that query all of the entities with the `Name` and `BestFriend` components and loop through that query to find the entity that matches the `BestFriend`'s stored ID.

My concerns about this method are:

- Can I be sure that the referenced entity ID will not be changed at some point?
- Having to loop through all the instances of the query seems inefficient.

As mentioned, the above case is just for the sake of example. I am more generally interested in learning patterns that allow entities to reference each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't have to "loop through" all instances of a query. Query lookups are typically implemented in such a way that they are fast -- often constant or logarithmic time complexity. Bevy queries have a `get` method for exactly this purpose:

```rust
#[derive(Component)]
struct BestFriend(Entity);

fn greet_best_friends(greeters: Query<(&Name, &BestFriend)>, friends: Query<&Name>) {
    for (greeter_name, &BestFriend(best_friend)) in greeters.iter() {
        let best_friend_name = friends
            .get(best_friend)
            .expect("My best friend got despawned!");
        println!(
            "Hello, I am {}, have a nice day {}",
            greeter_name, best_friend_name
        );
    }
}
```

In the example, I `panic!` if my `friends` query fails to find `greeter`'s friend because entity IDs are guaranteed to be stable and unique to a specific entity. If the `Entity` was returned by a call to `spawn`, it will remain valid until it is despawned. Let's go ahead and add some test entities:

```rust
let alice = world.spawn(Name::new("Alice")).id();
world.spawn((Name::new("Bob"), BestFriend(alice)));
```

Now when we run our system, the `greeters` query will match Bob since he has a name and best friend. Then we'll pull the ID of his best friend Alice and run it through our `friends` query (which only requires that Alice have a name) and say hello to her. We can be sure the query will complete properly unless Alice was despawned along the way.

As far as efficiency, the Bevy docs show that [`Query::get` has constant time complexity](https://docs.rs/bevy_ecs/latest/bevy_ecs/system/struct.Query.html#performance), so you don't need to worry about implementation potentially looping over many entities.

Comment: I have a question about some syntax you used in your example:

```struct BestFriend(Entity);```

What does the `(Entity)` part do, exactly? I haven't been able to find any examples of that syntax in either the Rust or Bevy documentation.

Comment: @accounted4 This defines the struct BestFriend as a [tuple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html) with a single member of type Entity. This appears to be the idiomatic way in Bevy to define a component that has exactly one field. You can find an example of this syntax in [the official quick start guide](https://bevyengine.org/learn/quick-start/getting-started/ecs/) where they use this pattern for the `struct Name(String);` component.